# Combining 2 bytes

Tags: c#, byte, bit-manipulation

I have a byte A and byte B. I am looking for byte C which is every other bit from A and every other bit from B. So if A = 10011010  and B = 01110010  then C would be 10110101 where 1011 is every other bit from A and 0101 is every other bit from B. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
byte C = (byte)(
    (A & 0x80) |
    ((A & 0x20) << 1) |
    ((A & 0x08) << 2) |
    ((A & 0x02) << 3) |
    ((B & 0x80) >> 4) |
    ((B & 0x20) >> 3) |
    ((B & 0x08) >> 2) |
    ((B & 0x02) >> 1));
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/1IBsp)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
var nibble1 = ((a & 0x80) << 3) | ((a & 0x20) << 2) |
              ((a & 0x08) << 1) | (a & 0x02);
var nibble2 = ((b & 0x80) << 3) | ((b & 0x20) << 2) |
              ((b & 0x08) << 1) | (b & 0x02);

var result = (nibble1 << 4) | nibble2;
```

For each input byte you take the "first" (actually it's customary to count starting from the other end, but I 'll go with that sounds more straightforward here) byte, shift it 3 places (to make room behind it for the others), add the "third" byte (shifting it two places) etc.

Then you shift the first nibble you just computed four places (to make space for the second) and stick them together.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = 154; //10011010
$b = 114; //01110010

$expected = 181; //10110101

$result = (($a>>1)&1)+(($a>>2)&2)+(($a>>3)&4)+(($a>>4)&8) << 4
          | (($b>>1)&1)+(($b>>2)&2)+(($b>>3)&4)+(($b>>4)&8);


echo $expected == $result;
```

Let me think about it for a little while, this could be done more efficiently...

Another one:

```
$a = 154; //10011010
$b = 114; //01110010

$expected = 181; //10110101

$result = ($a&0x80)+(($a<<1)&0x40)+(($a<<2)&0x20)+(($a<<3)&0x10)+
      (($b>>4)&0x8)+(($b>>3)&0x4)+(($b>>2)&0x2)+(($b>>1)&0x1);

echo $expected == $result;
```

...And *now* I notice the C# tag...